# LetsEncrypt Install on a Raspberry Pi web server

Tags: nginx, ssl, server, raspberry-pi

I've created a web server on my Raspberry Pi 4 and using it for a web project that I'm currently working on as well as future website projects. Currently, I'm running on Pop OS Linux distro on my main laptop and SSH to the Raspberry Pi running as a web server. I'd like to install the letsencrypt SSL on the webserver. I've found some tutorials on a Google search and have had no luck with the installation of certbot. I'm currently running the Nginx web server on the Raspberry Pi.

I have changed some of the settings on the /etc/Nginx/sites-available & sites-enabled and still no luck with the SSL running on the webserver. Are there any other suggestions or tips that anyone can throw my way to get this web server installed with a secure socket layer of encryption? I'm currently running the web server on my Raspberry Pi's IP Address. Maybe I need to change it to an actual domain name beforehand and see if that works?

When I run:
`sudo systemctl status nginx`

It returns as active. Which is good. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for following the steps, serially:

1. You need to register a domain name with a official DNS (Domain Name System) Register, e.g. [NameCheap](https://www.namecheap.com/), [Google Domains](https://domains.google/), [Go Daddy](https://www.godaddy.com).
2. Install certbot following instructions on [Let's Encrypt tutorials](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/) all SSL/TLS certificates will be installed automatically, (assuming that you're not requesting a wildcard certificate, I too recommend not doing so as it's a hassle in getting a wildcard certificate).
3. Make sure all ports are correctly forwarded to the Raspberry Pi and that there is no firewall interfering with the ports `443` and `80` and make sure that your ISP is not blocking them whatsoever, since Let's Encrypt needs to verify that your domain name and website exists and is accessible.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I'll try it out.

Comment: Please do Upvote my answer if it works out for you.

Comment: For wildcard certificates on NameCheap, I wrote and use this script.  Hope it's useful:
https://github.com/scribe777/letsencrypt-namecheap-dns-auth

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/ is a good tutorial; the link in the above answer is dead